# SQL explicit syntax sub query join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am trying to join in a number of fields from a sub query into the main and want to know how to write the join so that I avoid re defining my main table in the sub query.

I need to restrict the results from the sub query based on if it is a Holder or condition (aXM.ATTRIB_03) which is why I have tried to join via a sub query. The plan is to aggregate the conditions based on what is returned in the condition sub, see proposed output.

Although not shown in the code snippet it is also important that I return multiple results in each sub query.

I have been trying with the following query, this issue is that the sub query does not know about the alias '`Ass`'

> (ORA-00904: "ASS"."ROW_ID": invalid identifier)

```
SELECT 
  Ass.NAME AS REGISTER_NAME,
  Ass.ASSET_NUM AS SMSF_NUM,
  HOLDER.SMSF_HOLDER_TYPE,
  CONDITION.xCONDITION

FROM
  siebel.s_asset Ass

  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT aXM.par_row_id AS hCon, aXM.ATTRIB_44 AS SMSF_HOLDER_TYPE
    FROM Siebel.S_ASSET_XM aXM
    WHERE Ass.row_id = aXM.par_row_id
      AND aXM.ATTRIB_03 IS NULL
  ) HOLDER
  ON Ass.row_id = HOLDER.hCon

  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT aXM.par_row_id AS cCon, aXM.ATTRIB_44 AS xCONDITION
    FROM Siebel.S_ASSET_XM aXM
    WHERE Ass.row_id = aXM.par_row_id
      AND aXM.ATTRIB_03 = 'Condition'
  ) CONDITION
  ON Ass.row_id = CONDITION.cCon

WHERE
  AND Ass.NAME = 'SMSF Auditor'
  AND Ass.STATUS_CD = 'Registered'
```

Desired Output

```
REGISTER_NAME   SMSF_NUM    SMSF_HOLDER_TYPE        SMSF_CONDITION
SMSF Auditor    100259612   Individual Auditor      Condition 1~ Condition 2~ Condition 3
SMSF Auditor    100259747   Individual Auditor      Condition 1~ Condition 2~ Condition 3
SMSF Auditor    100259907   Individual Auditor      Condition 1~ Condition 2~ Condition 3
```

Comment: Your code is extremely convoluted. Please describe your actual task, provide some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: I apologize, this code snippet is part of a larger more complex query, I have tried to simplify as best I can. I will continue to update base on peoples feedback to try to help people understand what I am asking

Comment: You didnt include sample data. So we don't have anything to work to create your desire output.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ASS` alias in the inside query.

Try this. Looks like do the same.

```
SELECT 
  Ass.NAME AS REGISTER_NAME,
  Ass.ASSET_NUM AS SMSF_NUM,
  CASE
     WHEN aXM.ATTRIB_44 IS NULL THEN NULL 
  END AS SMSF_HOLDER_TYPE,
  CASE
     WHEN aXM.ATTRIB_44 IS NULL THEN NULL 
     ELSE aXM.ATTRIB_44
  END AS xCONDITION
FROM
  siebel.s_asset Ass
  LEFT JOIN Siebel.S_ASSET_XM aXM
    on Ass.row_id = aXM.par_row_id
WHERE
      Ass.NAME = 'SMSF Auditor'
  AND Ass.STATUS_CD = 'Registered'
  AND (aXM.ATTRIB_03 IS NULL OR aXM.ATTRIB_03 = 'Condition')
```

Comment: Yes that does work, the issue with that is that I need to restrict the results when joining to Siebel.S_ASSET_XM aXM for different reasons.
For example. 
S_ASSET_XM contains conditions and competency results. I want 1 sub query that returns only conditions and another that only returns competency results

Comment: Well then you should include that in your question. Sorry I can only solve the question I see.

Comment: I update the query to reflect your changes. Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: SMSF_HOLDER_TYPE `is nul` or `condition` dont know if you need two fields for that.

Comment: And would be easier if you provide a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c2bd/3) so we can work with real data and schema

Comment: Thanks Juan Carlos Oropeza. I think this may work in this particular case. I have run into this issue a number of times though (joining multiple fields from sub query to main query without re defining the main query table in the subs) Which is what I really trying to find out

Comment: Again, I can only answer to the question I see.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your query something like this

```
  SELECT 
  Ass.NAME AS REGISTER_NAME,
  Ass.ASSET_NUM AS SMSF_NUM,
  HOLDER.SMSF_HOLDER_TYPE

FROM
  siebel.s_asset Ass
  left join Siebel.S_ASSET_XM HOLDER on Ass.Ass.row_id = HOLDER.par_row_id
  inner join Siebel.S_ASSET_XM aXM ON Ass.row_id = aXM.par_row_id
```